# TeXworks - Two font isssues

Tags: texworks

I know this is not a latex related question - but its with texworks so thought to ask here. 
I have some data in excel which I want to bring it to Tex file so that I can create nice pdf file.

When I copy data from excel and paste in texworks only one type of font gets copied based on texworks font preference and the second one is totally messed up as shown in the image. Is there any work around for this?

The font I am working are "Arsha Sanskrit" and "Airel" This is how I got the file and I really don't want to retype the whole document.

They both work fine separately but gets one correct rendering based on the texworks preference.

I would appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: How is this a problem? The font used in the LaTeX editor has no influence on the font used in the PDF.

Answer (score 3):

TeXworks can only use one font at the time in the GUI, but this does not, I think, influence the result you see in the PDF created by LaTeX. In order to see both Sanskrit and Latin letters rendered correctly in TeXworks, you would have to find a font that contains the glyphs from both alphabets.

Comment: how would I know if the font contains the glyphs from both alphabets.

Comment: @Raama You would have to try, I guess. I never write with any other alphabet than the Latin one, so I'm not familiar with what fonts cover other alphabets. Sorry, I can't be of more help.